# Should "How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files" be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I noticed that if you search google for "[word to text command line](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+to+text+command+line)" the very first result is a closed question on Stack Overflow:

[How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files? (unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix)

Although it's closed as off topic, the fact that it's the top search result suggests that it has gotten something right! Shouldn't it be migrated to another site? Software Recommendations was suggested in comments, but it seems like a candidate for Super User as well. In any case, it's a shame that the most useful link addressing this question is closed and posted on the wrong site. Seems like a broken window.

I should add that I don't see it as a "shopping list" question, although I see that it is worded in a way that might invite that interpretation. The title says "how to," and I think that's the right interpretation. I think it *is* off-topic -- but I don't think it would be on another site.

(I could have just flagged, but I don't think I have a good handle on the right way to propose migrations, so I decided to ask.)

Comment: Yes - migrated into nonexistence.

Comment: *"it's the top search result"* - it's SO good, not that specific question. This should normally occurs with any other question. Over past years different e.g. C# sites moving down and SO up, it's over msdn currently. It wasn't my decision to avoid "asking for library" questions (that's solid amount of traffic), but I am forced to support it. Is it good or bad we will see in 10 years, maybe some other network will take over SO if they allow such questions, /shrug

Comment: *"The fact that it's the top search result suggests that it has gotten something right."* Indeed. What it has gotten right is that people have found it helpful and useful.  But of course SO is not primarily interested in being helpful and useful.  SO's prime directive is to build a high-quality repository of answers to high-quality questions, but this question is (per SO's rules) not high-quality, which leads to the results you see.

Answer (score 16):

## No.

The question doesn't deserve to be migrated *anywhere*.

Migration is a function which allows us to move a question **which is otherwise *good* but a better fit somewhere else**.

So let's ask ourselves:  is the question *good*?

## No, it's *not* a good question.

The question is tacitly and explicitly [asking for a shopping list](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which is not a form of question we want to support ***anywhere*** on the network.

This is also evidenced by the answers which are just throwing recommendations out there as "try this"-style solutions.  None of these are going to redeem the question.

Irrespective of what attention it's received from SEO over the years, this question just isn't good.  Because it's not good, [we shouldn't be migrating it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/175248)

(Besides, migrations for content *that* old can't happen at all since it's beyond thresholds for even diamond moderators.  An employee probably *could* do it but given the damning evidence against it, chances of that happening are nil.)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but to me, it didn't read as a shopping list request. It read to me as a "how do I" question. But I can see how someone might disagree.

Comment: @senderle - Are phrases like "Anyone know of anything they can recommend" or "wondered if there were any other suggestions" not enough of a hint in this context...?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "enough of a hint." I see why someone might see those phrases and conclude that this is a shopping list question -- sure. To be clear, that's why I said "But I can see how someone might disagree." It's just not *my* conclusion, after reading and considering the question as a whole.

Comment: "The question is tacitly and explicitly asking for a shopping list, which is not a form of question we want to support anywhere on the network." - Can you please discuss [softwarerecs.se] specifically?

Comment: @Kevin:  I'd argue that it's an anomaly.  The blog post in 2010 clearly didn't motivate a site like Software Recommendations coming about; it was borne out of a pain here on Stack Overflow because users just *kept* posting about software recs. To this day I still have a hard time sending people along to Software Recommendations because it would feel like I'm throwing trash over the fence in *many* contexts.

Comment: @Kevin:  It's also the case that Software Recs isn't really going for "shopping list"-style questions *anyway*.  [There's a lot of meaty details](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) in what they expect a question to contain and what is or isn't acceptable there.  The stereotypical "shopping-list" question is just a set of requirements with no scope or bound, which is the question we're actually discussing right now.

Comment: @Kevin: I would guess that almost every recommendation question on [main] or elsewhere (e.g. [softwareengineering.se] also gets a lot of them) cannot be migrated to [softwarerecs.se] because it would not meet their quality standards and thus be off-topic there. They have those quality standards precisely *because* of the same reasons that recommendation questions are off-topic on almost all sites, in order to prevent and avoid the problems because of which those kinds of questions are unwelcome almost everywhere.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: That's fine, but if you make a blanket statement such as "shopping list questions are not a form of question we want to support anywhere on the network," you really should not be surprised when people bring up SR.

Comment: @Kevin: I would argue that the rules put in place on [softwarerecs.se] are precisely to ensure that shopping-list questions are off-topic there as well. The requirement to have a user story / use case / statement of purpose, a requirements specification, to show your research, they are all there to ensure that the question does not devolve into a shopping-list.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: And I never said otherwise.

Comment: I disagree with this take. The top-voted answer purports to do this with nothing but standard Unix command-line tools. What's more, it's clear that the asker is *not* asking purely for tool recommendations, because the example they link to of any approach they've already seen is [a short Python-based solution using no third-party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364/1709587). If this is a shopping list question, then every how-to question for which a third-party tool could conceivably be useful is a shopping list question.

Comment: While I agree this isn't a great question, there are a host of problems with this answer and followup comments. First "Migration is a function which allows us to move a question which is otherwise good but a better fit somewhere else." this is incorrect; questions don't have to be "otherwise good for SO". A question can be quite bad, e.g. blatantly off-topic on SO, and be a great migration candidate because it's on-topic on another site instead. Second, the question's not a shopping list, but others have already explained that one. Third, because you don't personally approve of [1/2]

Comment: (cont'd) Software Recs has no bearing on the fact that, in reality, it's an equal site on the network, not some "well we need some place to direct undesirable content..." The argument that it is such a place falls apart when you consider they impose standards on the type and quality of questions that are allowed/on-topic there. [2/2]

Comment: @TylerH:  A question which is objectively *bad* means it's *also* a bad fit for SO.  A question which is objectively good but not a fit for SO is the only point in which "migration" becomes an option.  Not sure how this was conflated; I never mentioned "otherwise good for SO" as an option.

Comment: Also @TylerH:  I at least correct myself with my second response after looking a bit closer at what standards of questions they expect on their site, but I could be forgiven for assuming what kind of site it is, given that people who ask questions *just like the one we're discussing in the OP* often get referred to Software Recommendations, and often without any context or framing or expectation of quality.  Honestly, it sounds familiar.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  Yikes.  I didn't even _look_ at that question.  I'd vote for a historical lock; sure, it's valuable but it's not an example of a good question (and it's ironic that it's being used as a defense of this question).

Comment: @Makoto I don't see what's so terribly wrong with either, and have voted to reopen this one. They ask what seems to me like a widely-applicable and reasonably well-defined task, and people provide straightforward solutions in a few lines of code. What's the problem? Isn't that what we're here for?

Comment: @MarkAmery:  I'm thinking that the question - [this question specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482/1079354) - would be considered "Too Broad" by today's standards.  That's also why I'd advocate for a historical lock; this question probably does have some value, but it's ***definitely*** not a good example of the kinds of questions we want here.

Comment: @Makoto I agree that a question which is objectively bad is also a bad fit for SO. However, what you said in the answer, "otherwise good but a better fit for another site", to me at least, means it has to be somewhat "good" even on SO. A great question for SoftwareRecs.SE would never be a "good" question for SO. Likewise a great question for DIY.SE would never be a good question for SO.

Comment: @TylerH:  That was a response given in context.  In context to *the site we're currently on* (which would be Stack Overflow), the question is *not* "otherwise good".  Therefore, migration is not a viable path for it because we don't want to [give anyone the impression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/175248) that we're migrating crap.

Comment: @TylerH:  It is **thoroughly unreasonable** to ask someone to look at a question as objectively on-topic for a network site that they're not affiliated with, and I'm not imposing that constraint. I'm just saying, "is the question where it is today a *good* question?"  If it is, but it's just off-topic here, then *maybe* it can be migrated.  If it isn't, then we should just deal with it here.

Comment: @Makoto any question that is otherwise good **on SO** doesn't *need* to be migrated or deleted, but simply *could* be. And I'm not talking about just the few sites we have built-in migration paths for, but a migration from SO to *any* site (I know it's not so simply done in practice). I agree it's unreasonable to expect voters to be aware of every site and their rules; this isn't a normal case, it's a special situation being discussed on Meta where the sky is the limit. And to be clear, the question we are discussing I think is rightfully closed and not worth migrating anywhere.

Comment: @TylerH:  Right...once more with feeling.   What we're determining here is if the question is *good*.  That happens **first**. If the question *isn't* good, then we shouldn't be thinking about migration.  If the question *is* good, then we can see if it would be a better fit elsewhere, and it may not be.  What we've established here, on Meta, is that this question has failed the first check; it's not a good question, so migration should be off the table at this point.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the question wasn't closed until 4 years ago; it spent the 4 years after it was posted *NOT* closed.

It was closed to illustrate the point that it's not really the kind of question we're looking for, but the upvotes clearly show that it has proven useful.

I don't think there's any problem with it being closed, with regard to its position in external search results. The fact that it is closed surely doesn't mean the information is somehow "invalid".

As far as the question of whether or not to migrate it, the first rule of migration is [Don't Migrate Crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/362452), and since the question is *definitely* off-topic and seeking recommendations, there's no point in trying to foist it off on anyone else.

Comment: A question can be both useful and off topic. Both aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Braiam: I guess I don't understand your point. The cited question is closed because it *is* off-topic.

Comment: I certainly don't think there's any particular problem with it being closed on Stack Overflow, since it's not on topic for Stack Overflow. That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @senderle: Could you clarify, then? I read your question to say that you didn't think it should be ranked highly in search results because it is closed.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, do my edits clarify at all? My precise point is really that I think it would be on-topic on another site. And the benefit of having it be open would be to invite updates and new answers, as things change over time. If the consensus is that it is indeed a shopping list question as [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/383136/577088) thinks, that's fine. It won't change my mind but I can accept that outcome.

Comment: Closed is just the previous step towards deletion. At that point, useful information or not will be lost. Migration is a way to prevent information loses.

Comment: @Braiam: The question does not fit the criteria for automatic deletion by the system, so it would have to be deleted explicitly by someone. I don't think that's going to happen.

Comment: @senderle: I agree with Makoto that the question is *definitely* off-topic; there's no doubt that it *should* be closed. And the first rule of migration is [Don't Migrate Crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/362452), so that's pretty much a non-starter. I suppose you could inquire on the meta-sites of all of the other SE websites and see if anyone wants it, but that would be time-consuming.

Comment: Eh... Off-topic is one of the specific reasons we _do_ migrate for (in fact, we shouldn't migrate questions that aren't off-topic). Just because it's off-topic here, doesn't mean it's off-topic elsewhere. E.g. software recommendation questions are fine on [softwarerecs.se]. Don't migrate crap applies to too broad/unclear/badly written. However, I don't think there's a site where this question is on-topic.

Comment: @Braiam no. Closure is closure, deletion is deletion. The fact that badly received closed questions will be deleted automatically by the system does not mean that closure "is just the previous step towards deletion". It just means those questions are **that bad**. This not a good question, but it was well received (as proven by its score and answers), so I doubt it will ever get deleted.

Comment: "and since the question is definitely [...] seeking recommendations, there's no point in trying to foist it off on anyone else." What if there is a site specifically for seeking recommendations? One site's off-topic could be [another site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)'s gem.